# Difference between 'urbe' and 'oppidum'?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, word-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I have found that LLPSI uses *oppidum* to describe cities (at least in the early chapters) while Duolingo uses *urbe*. What is the difference, and which should I usually use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [*urbs*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=urbs&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is a city, an [*oppidum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=oppidum&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is a town.

It is quite common to use *urbs* to refer specifically to Rome, and the linked dictionary entry even says that *oppidum* is used for other cities than Rome.
You could say that *urbs* is a capital and *oppidum* is a regular city.
There are a number of ways to phrase and see it, but the crux is: *urbs* is bigger (in size or importance) than *oppidum*.

See the links to dictionary entries for more details.

The word *urbe* is the ablative form of *urbs*.

Comment: Browsing the relevant entries in the OLD, I found an interesting example from Livy 31.27: "hic metus Codrionem, satis validum et munitum oppidum, sine certamine ut dederetur Romanis effecit, praesidio ibi relicto, Cnidus—nomen propter alteram in Asia urbem quam oppidum notius—vi capitur.

Comment: @AlexB. That is indeed interesting. Would you translate that as "a name better known for another Asian city than a town"? I find that sentence confusing, a feeling familiar from when I took a Livy course a decade ago...

Comment: I read it as [nomen notius quam oppidum] propter [alteram in Asia urbem], i.e. "a name better known than the town itself because of another town/city in Asia". It's like talking about St. Petersburg in Florida and St. Petersburg in Russia